# How to Hardcode a wifi hotspot/SSID in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hotspot, windows-registry

I have been searching for a way to force several Windows 10 Laptops to only be able to connect to a specific hotspot/SSID.

Backstory:
These laptops are used for charity events and are wiped at the end of the day. We run scripts to set them up for the events.
These laptops are ideally to be connected to a specific wifi ssid for networking. No internet access.
Multiple users get on theses systems and we don't want the average user to be able to switch wifi hotspots.

Maybe a registry entry I could make?

Comment: Have you tried revoking the permissions to change wifi networks from everyone but the administrator? I believe you can do that in both domain and non-domain GPO.

Comment: Hi adonalsium, no I have not tried this. Where might the settings be located?  I was not able to find anything to do with Wifi settings in the GPO on the PC.

Comment: @Adonalsium please see previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to configure this in Local Group Policy, which only the Local Admin account(s) will be able to modify.

1. Open **gpedit.msc** (*Group Policy Management Editor*)
2. Navigate to **Computer Configuration > Policies > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Wireless Network... Policies**
3. Click **Action > Create A New Wireless Network Policy...**
4. Enable **Use Windows WLAN AutoConfig service for clients** (this will prevent third party wireless management apps from messing things up).
5. In the **Network Permissions** tab choose the appropriate options and add networks to allow or deny.

Comment: Thank you for the information. However I am having trouble finding any Wireless Network Policies under **Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Wireless Network... Policies**

The best I could locate was **Computer Configuration > Administrative templates > network > WLAN service**  however the settings there do not look like they will help.   Caveat - I am not on the specific PCs but a different windows 10 PC.

Comment: please see previous comment. @music2myear

Comment: Does the computer you are on have wireless capability? Have you checked the GP Editor on the computer you're trying to set up?

Comment: Some people suggest that if you're missing these and your computer does have wireless capability, you may with to uninstall all drivers for wireless devices and then reinstall them.

Comment: @music2myyear unfortunately I have looked at multiple Laptops with wireless and have not found that in GP. 
[http://i63.tinypic.com/2j7ehk.png](http://i63.tinypic.com/2j7ehk.png)